# Efficient Cab scheduling

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, combinations, permutation

I came across this technical question while preparation. There are K cabs. ith cab takes ki minutes to complete any trip. What is the minimum time it will take to complete N trips with these K cabs. We can assume there is no waiting time in between trips, and different cabs can take trips simultaneously. Can anyone suggest efficient algorithm to solve this.

Example:

```
Input:
N=3 K=2
K1 takes 1 minute, K2 takes 2 minutes

Output:
2 minutes

Explanation: Both cabs starts trip at t=0. At t=1, first cab starts third trip. So by t=2, required 3 trips will be completed
```

Comment: When N is large, you can reduce the problem by computing the [least common multiple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple)(LCM) of the `k_i`. In your example k1=1 and k2=2, so the LCM(k1,k2)=2. Which means that the cabs can do 3 trips in 2 minutes, and then all of the cabs are available. So for example if N=14, the cabs can do 12 trips in 8 minutes, and the problem is reduced to N=2 with all the cabs available.

Comment: https://leetcode.com/problems/minimum-time-to-complete-trips/ The equivalent LC problem for the same.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Binary search seems pretty intuitive and simple. Let's reframe the question:

> Given a time `t`, compute the maximum number of trips that can be taken.

We can do this in `O(K)`. Consider that each cab `i` can take up to `t / k_i` trips in `t` time, and we can simply get the sum of all `t / k_i` for each `i` to get the maximum number of trips taken in `t` time. This lets us build a function we can binary search over:

```
def f(time):
    n_trips = 0
    for trip_time in cabs:
        n_trips += time // trip_time
    return n_trips
```

Obviously it follows that as we increase the amount of time, the amount of trips we can take will also increase, so `f(x)` is non-decreasing, which means we can run a binary search on it.

We binary search for the minimum `t` that gives `N` or more trips as the output, and this can be done in `O(KlogW)`, where `W` is the range of all `t` we have to consider.

Comment: If `K` equals `N`, can we solve it in [O(sqrt(K) log(W))](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_summatory_function#Dirichlet's_divisor_problem)?

Answer (score 3):

```cpp
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int solve(int arr[],int n,int k,int mid)

{

    int trip=0;

    for(int i=0;i<k;i++)

    {

        trip+=(mid/arr[i]);

        if(trip>=n)

        return 1;

    }

    return 0;

}

int main()

{ 

   int n, k;


   cin>>n>>k;

   int arr[k];

   for(int i=0;i<k;i++)

   {

       cin>>arr[i];

   }
    
  int ans=INT_MAX;

  int l=0,h=1e9;

  while(l<=h)

  {

      int mid=l+(h-l)/2;

      if(solve(arr,n,k,mid))

      {

          ans=mid;

          h=mid-1;
      }

      else

      {

          l=mid+1;

      }

  }

  cout<<ans;

  return 0;

}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: @blazej, the core thought here is to assume the answer instead of calculating it and then see if the answer you assumed actually qualifies as an answer or not; or is there any scope to optimize it further. Keep assuming and validating it until you have the most optimized number through the help of binary search approach. Also note that this works only when the input array is sorted.

Answer (score 1):

Java Solution as per as @Primusa suggested algo

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class EfficientCabScheduling {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = sc.nextInt();
    int k = sc.nextInt();
    int[] kArr = new int[k];

    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
      kArr[i] = sc.nextInt();
    }

    System.out.println(solve(n, kArr));
  }

  private static int solve(int n, int[] kArr) {
    int l = 0;
    int h = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int m = h + (l - h) / 2;
    while (l < h) {
      m = h + (l - h) / 2;
      int trips = 0;
      for (int k : kArr) {
        trips += (m / k);
      }
      if (trips == n) {
        break;
      } else if (trips < n) {
        l = m + 1;
      } else {
        h = m - 1;
      }
    }
    return m;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It really helped me to understand

Comment: `if(trips == n) break` isn't correct.

Answer (score 0):

we can iterate to check number of possible trips for each min and print the min at which our total no of trip become equal to N
taking N as integer and K as array of trip time of cab:

```
def efficientCabScheduling(N, K):
if len(K)==1:
    eftime=N*K[0]
else:
    trip=0
    eftime=0
    while trip<N:
        eftime+=1
        for ch in K:
            if eftime%ch==0:
                trip+=1


return eftime
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the JavaScript solution for efficient cab scheduling problem by Uber.

The approach here is find a `time` that meets the condition for `targetTrips`.

This can be done by doing a binary search.
Since the problem say `Min` - if we find a value -> just traverse backwards until target is valid.

```
/**
 *
 * @param {number} time
 * @param {list[number]} cabTripTime
 * @param {number} targetTrip
 * @returns {number}
 */
function targetMet(time,cabTripTime, targetTrip){
  // simply iterate over all the values until trip is met. of return the sum

    let trips = 0
    for(let i = 0;i<cabTripTime.length;i++){
        trips = trips + Math.floor((time/cabTripTime[i]))
       // break if target is found
        if(trips===targetTrip){
            return trips
        }
     // this is an optimization. Not really needed. Good for large numbers
        if(trips>targetTrip){
            return trips
        }

    }
    return trips
}

/**
 *
 * @param {number} n
 * @param {list[number]} cabTripTime
 * @returns {number}
 */
function efficientCabScheduling(n,cabTripTime){
    // rename variable for clarity
    const targetTrip = n

    //  set up for binary search
    // right bound
    let timeMax = Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER
    // left bound
    let timeMin = 0


    // binary search until target is found
    while(timeMin<=timeMax){
        let time = Math.floor((timeMax+timeMin)/2)
        const trips = targetMet(time,cabTripTime,targetTrip)
        if(trips===targetTrip){

            // iterate to left until you find another min
            // there are cases where the value BS found can me the max
            // problem statement say MIN
            // for example [1,2,3,3,4]
            while(targetMet((time -1),cabTripTime,targetTrip)===targetTrip){
                time --
            }
            return time

        }else{
            // binary search change bounds
            if(trips>targetTrip){
                timeMax = time -1
            }else{
                timeMin = time +1
            }
        }
    }

    return 0
}

const testCase1 = efficientCabScheduling(3,[1,2])===2
const testCase2 = efficientCabScheduling(10,[1,3,5,7])===7
const testCase3 = efficientCabScheduling(10,[1,3,5,7])===0

console.log(testCase1)
console.log(testCase2)
console.log(testCase3)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
'''

Using a binary search approach here ,
i take the execution time as   l(least time) = 0 ,  r (max_time) = 10^14, 
to get the exec time = mid = (l+r )/2 
Now this mid is used to calculate the total trips by iterate over the array .
ONce the sum_of_trips > TOTAL_trips 
    we decrease  the mid by , r := mid
else:
    l = mid+1
TIME COMPLEXITY =  O( log(K) * N )
N= no. of cabs
K = max_exec_time possible , here it is 10^14

'''


import math
class Solution:
 
    def minimumTime(self, time: List[int], totalTrips: int) -> int:
        l = 0 
        r = math.pow(10, 14)
        mid = 0
        ans = r 
        while l < r :
            
            mid = int((l+r)/2) # here mid is the exec time of the total trips 
            
            ct = 0
            
            for t in time:
                ct += math.floor(mid/t)
            
            if ct >= totalTrips:
                
                ans = min(ans , mid )
                r = mid 
            else:
                l = mid+1
        return int(ans)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).